Why Azure AD B2C Session Still Active while I logged Out?
I implement my react app with Azure AD B2C and I configure Single sign-on configuration of the User Flow as Application, not Tenant.
When I sign out, it clears the token from local storage but does not clear the Azure AD B2C session. that's why when click on sign in again it logs me in without asking for my credentials.
Question: why is Azure AD B2C session still active while I logged out?
Expectation: Azure AD B2C Session should be cleared when signed out
The code of log out function here:
    const { instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
    let activeAccount;

    if (instance) {
        activeAccount = instance.getActiveAccount();
    }

    const handleLoginPopup = () => {
        instance
            .loginPopup({
                ...loginRequest,
                redirectUri: '/',
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };

    const handleLoginRedirect = () => {
        instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };

    const handleLogoutRedirect = () => {
        instance.logoutRedirect();
    };

    const handleLogoutPopup = () => {
        instance.logoutPopup({
            mainWindowRedirectUri: '/', // redirects the top level app after logout
        });
    };

    const handleProfileEdit = () => {
        if (inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
            instance.acquireTokenRedirect(b2cPolicies.authorities.editProfile);
        }
    };

here is the user flow that I configured in Azure AD B2C:


Can you share your code in the question?

Hi Dasari, I have added the code in the question

Share your code in text format not in image

updated. here you go

When you log out, Azure AD B2C should clear the session cookies. However, sometimes these cookies persist, leading to automatic sign-ins.

I tried a sample React project with Azure AD B2C login with configuration of the User Flow as Application. My page looks like this and I got this page after clicking on Login button. I manually entered my credentials for login. After logged in I got Logout button page as this.

When you use Azure AD B2C to log in to your React app, you might find that the session doesn’t always end right away after you log out.

This happens because even though your app clears out the local tokens, Azure AD B2C might still keep its session cookies.
So, when you sign in again, it might do so automatically without asking for your credentials again.

I tried the below sample React app to login with Azure AD B2C.
authConfig.js :
import { LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';

export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '<client_ID>',
        authority: 'https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_Name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy_name>',
        knownAuthorities: ['<tenant_Name>.b2clogin.com'],
        redirectUri: '/', 
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', 
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        break;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        break;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        break;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
};

App.js  :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMsal, useIsAuthenticated } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { loginRequest } from './authConfig';

function App() {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
    const [isInteractionInProgress, setIsInteractionInProgress] = useState(false);
    const [setProfile] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated && accounts.length > 0) {
            instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                ...loginRequest,
                account: accounts[0],
            }).then((response) => {
                setProfile(response.idTokenClaims);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    }, [instance, accounts, isAuthenticated]);

    const handleLoginRedirect = () => {
        if (!isInteractionInProgress) {
            setIsInteractionInProgress(true);
            instance.loginRedirect({
                ...loginRequest,
            }).finally(() => {
                setIsInteractionInProgress(false);
            });
        } else {
            console.warn('Login interaction is in progress.');
        }
    };
    
    const handleLogoutRedirect = () => {
        if (!isInteractionInProgress) {
            setIsInteractionInProgress(true);
            instance.logoutRedirect({
                postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', 
            }).finally(() => {
                setIsInteractionInProgress(false);
            });
        } else {
            console.warn('Logout interaction is in progress.');
        }
    };
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to My App</h1>
                {!isAuthenticated ? (
                    <button onClick={handleLoginRedirect}>Login</button>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <button onClick={handleLogoutRedirect}>Logout</button>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
export default App;

index.js :
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
ReactDOM.render(
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <App />
    </MsalProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

Output :
The following code ran successfully as below,

Browser Output :
I got the below page in the browser. I clicked on Login button as shown below,

I manually entered my credentials for login in the below page,

I successfully logged in and got the below for Logout as shown below.


hi, the issue is after you logout successfully and then you click login button again it will automatically sign you in without asking your credentials when the user flow configured Application in the Single Sign On Configuration. where as if you change to Tenant for the Single Sign On Configuration, then the log out button clear both token at your local app and the session of Azure AD B2C as well.

Thank you for the clarification. You're correct; setting the Single Sign-On configuration to 'Tenant' instead of 'Application' ensures that the local tokens and the Azure AD B2C session are cleared on logout, preventing automatic sign-in without re-authentication.
